# Download zip file from activeadmin batch action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, download, activeadmin

I want to `send_data` to the admin who is using the activeadmin interface in our website. This data is a zip file and can be downloaded if certain conditions on the selected items are met.

I created a service that handles the logic (quite complex) behind it. So from activeadmin I can call:

```
batch_action :action_name, form: {selection: ['...']} do |ids, inputs|
  response = MyService.new(ids, inputs[:selection]).my_method
  redirect_to collection_path
end
```

In my service `MyService.rb`:

```
...
def my_method
  ...
  if condition
    zip_data = Zip::OutputStream.write_buffer do |zip|
      zip.put_next_entry("#{original_file_name}.xml")
      zip << File.read(original_file)
    end
    send_data(zip_data.read, :type => 'application/zip', :filename => "#{original_file_name}.zip")
    # here send_data throws an error because it's a controller method
  else
    ...
  end
  ...
end
...
```

But how do I use the `send_data` method properly? Maybe I have to restructure something? I know you can probably do `ActionController::DataStreaming.send_data(...)` outside of the controller, but this is not recommended for the code's sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I put the `send_data`in the `batch_action` code like this:

```
batch_action :action_name, form: {selection: ['...']} do |ids, inputs|
  response = MyService.new(ids, inputs[:selection]).my_method
  redirect_to collection_path
  send_data(response[:zip][:data].read, :type => 'application/zip', :filename => "#{response[:zip][:name]}.zip") if response[:zip].present?
end
```

where the response contains the zip data to send (which needs to be rewinded with `zip_data.rewind` before being sent). `my_service.rb` is now like:

```
...
def my_method
  ...
  if condition
    zip_data = Zip::OutputStream.write_buffer do |zip|
      zip.put_next_entry("#{original_file_name}.xml")
      zip << File.read(original_file)
    end
    zip_data.rewind
    response[:zip] = {data: zip_data, name: original_file_name}
  else
    ...
  end
  ...
end
...
```